# pdo search trouble undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I'm doing a mvc crud with search engine but when I run the project shows Fatal error: Call to undefined method client::buscame() in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc \ view \ client \ client.php on line 56

this is  /view/cliente/cliente.php

```
<h1 class="page-header">CRUD con el patrón MVC en PHP POO y PDO </h1>


<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=agregar">Agregar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=ardila">Ardila</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=mateus">Mateus</a>
```

```
<table class="table  table-striped  table-hover" id="tabla">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">ID</th>
    <th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">DNI</th>
        <th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Nombre</th>
        <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Apellido</th>
        <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Correo</th>
        <th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Telefono</th>            
        <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
        <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($this->model->Listar() as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->dni; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Nombre; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Apellido; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Correo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Telefono; ?></td>
        <td>
<a  class="btn btn-warning" href="?c=cliente&a=agregar&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>">Editar</a>
        </td>
        <td>
<a  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="javascript:return confirm('¿Seguro de eliminar este registro?');" href="?c=cliente&a=Eliminar&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>">Eliminar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

```
        <form action="?c=cliente&a=buscame" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni"/>
            <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>

        </form>

        <?php while($f= $this->model->buscame()){ 
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td width="19">'.$f['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td width="61">'.$f['dni'].'</td>';
            echo '<td width="157">'.$f['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo '<td width="221">'.$f['Apellido'].'</td>';
            echo '<td width="176">'.$f['Correo'].'</td>';
            echo '<td width="118">'.$f['Telefono'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>

</tbody>
```

and this is cliente.controller.php

class clienteController{

```
private $model;

public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    $this->model = new cliente();
}

public function Paginar(){
    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/cliente/cliente.php';

}

public function agregar(){
    $cliente = new cliente();

    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $cliente = $this->model->Obtener($_REQUEST['id']);
    }

    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/cliente/cliente-editar.php';

}


public function buscame(){
    $cliente = new cliente();
    $dni=$_GET('dni');
    if(isset($dni)){
         $stm = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id= :id');
         $stm -> bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stm -> execute(); 
         $res = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         if(empty($res) or $res == false){
        return array();}
      else{
    return $res;}

    }
    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/cliente/cliente.php';

}






public function ardila(){
    $cliente = new cliente();

    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $cliente = $this->model->ListarApellido($_REQUEST['id']);
    }

    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/cliente/Lista.php';

}

public function mateus(){
    $cliente = new cliente();

    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $cliente = $this->model->ListarApellidoM($_REQUEST['id']);
    }

    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/cliente/Lista.php';

}


public function Guardar(){
    $cliente = new cliente();

    $cliente->id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $cliente->dni = $_REQUEST['dni'];
    $cliente->Nombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
    $cliente->Apellido = $_REQUEST['Apellido'];
    $cliente->Correo = $_REQUEST['Correo'];  
    $cliente->telefono = $_REQUEST['telefono'];    
  if($cliente->id > 0){
      $this->model->Actualizar($cliente);
  }

  else{
      $this->model->Registrar($cliente);
  } 
    header('Location: index.php');
}

public function Eliminar(){
    $this->model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['id']);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

}

when I do a search, Fatal error appears:

> Call to undefined method client::buscame() in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \
>   mvc \ view \ client \ client.php on line 56

Comment: The function `buscame` is not declared in `cliente` class. Try change: `$this->model->buscame()` - to - `$this->buscame()`

Comment: In `clienteController` class, inside `buscame()` function, change two variables named `$dni` to `$id`. The function will most likely not retrieve results without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided all your code but it would appear you don't have a method `buscame()` on the model you're calling in the view.

`$this->model->buscame()`

Is it possible you mean to do something such as

`$this->client->buscame()`